# aggregate pivot in pandas with multiple repeated fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id       Field_name  Field_value
1           consent          yes
1   _REACTION TIME_         5547
1              age            24
1           gender             X
1   _REACTION TIME_        45396
1         education          uni
1          language           EN
1   _REACTION TIME_       105187
2           consent          yes
2   _REACTION TIME_         3547
2              age            25
2           gender             F
2   _REACTION TIME_        42396
2         education          uni
2          language           EU
2   _REACTION TIME_       115427
```

and I would like to have it as a row per id, with every `_REACTION TIME_` row being a different column, such as:

```
id  consent  _REACTION TIME_1  age gender  _REACTION TIME_2  education language _REACTION TIME_3
1       yes              5547   24      X             45396        uni       EN           105187
2       yes              3547   25      F             42396        uni       EU           115427
```

I have been looking for an answer to this all over SO but I can't find it for this particular issue when only some of the entries are repeated, but they are repeated multiple times.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) only for rows with duplicates by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), so possible pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), last for original order of columns add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
m = df.duplicated(['id','Field_name'], keep=False)
df.loc[m, 'Field_name'] += df[m].groupby(['id','Field_name']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

cols = df['Field_name'].unique()
df = df.pivot(index='id', columns='Field_name', values='Field_value').reindex(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
Field_name consent _REACTION TIME_1 age gender _REACTION TIME_2 education  \
id                                                                          
1              yes             5547  24      X            45396       uni   
2              yes             3547  25      F            42396       uni   

Field_name language _REACTION TIME_3  
id                                    
1                EN           105187  
2                EU           115427
```

Solution avoiding overwrite original DataFrame is similar:

```
m = df.duplicated(['id','Field_name'], keep=False)
s = df['Field_name'].add(df.groupby(['id','Field_name']).cumcount().add(1)
                           .astype(str)).where(m, df['Field_name'])


df1 = (df.assign(Field_name=s)
        .pivot(index='id', columns='Field_name', values='Field_value')
        .reindex(s.unique(), axis=1))
print (df1)
Field_name consent _REACTION TIME_1 age gender _REACTION TIME_2 education  \
id                                                                          
1              yes             5547  24      X            45396       uni   
2              yes             3547  25      F            42396       uni   

Field_name language _REACTION TIME_3  
id                                    
1                EN           105187  
2                EU           115427
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remain `_REACTION TIME_` instead of renaming it as `_REACTION TIME_1` in column header, you can do `groupby.apply`

```py
out = (df.groupby('id').apply(lambda g: g.drop('id', axis=1).set_index('Field_name').T)
       .reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)
       .rename_axis('', axis=1))
```

```
print(out)

   id consent _REACTION_TIME_ age gender _REACTION_TIME_ education language _REACTION_TIME_
0   1     yes            5547  24      X           45396       uni       EN          105187
1   2     yes            3547  25      F           42396       uni       EU          115427
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Although this code is much easier to follow than that of the other answer, it creates 2 more columns, one with  `level_1` as the column name and `Field_value` as the value and the other with `Field_name` as the column name. Is there a way to fix this directly on the method call?